# How is this form designed

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, forms

ok, so the RSPB have a very cool form which they use as a bird identifier

https://www.rspb.org.uk/birds-and-wildlife/bird-and-wildlife-guides/bird-identifier/

I am sure it deals with a SQL database in the back end but not sure how the form speaks to it and gets one result from asking multiple questions.

I would be very grateful if someone could give me the correct name for the process or give a super high level guide as to how it might work? I have this in mind for another subject (not birds) and it could be very helpful.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 1):

It makes an AJAX request specifying the filters, then the server sends the results back in JSON format...

Like:
https://www.rspb.org.uk/includes/birdidentifier.asp?size=1&feathers=black,red&habitats=Farmland

Its "normal" way of doing things in web development.

If you have chrome, you can view the "Network" tab inside the develompent tools to see all the requests done.